# NLTK words lemmatizing

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, stemming, lemmatization

I am trying to do lemmatization on words with `NLTK`.

What I can find now is that I can use the `stem` package to get some results like transform "cars" to "car" and "women" to "woman", however I cannot do lemmatization on some words with affixes like "acknowledgement".

When using `WordNetLemmatizer()` on "acknowledgement", it returns "acknowledgement" and using `.PorterStemmer()`, it returns "acknowledg" rather than "acknowledge".

Can anyone tell me how to eliminate the affixes of words?
Say, when input is "acknowledgement", the output to be "acknowledge"

Comment: Have you considered some of the other lemmatizers in `nltk`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lemmatization does not (and should not) return "acknowledge" for "acknowledgement". The former is a verb, while the latter is a noun. Porter's stemming algorithm, on the other hand, simply uses a fixed set of rules. So, your only way there is to change the rules at source. (NOT the right way to fix your problem).

What you are looking for is the derivationally related form of "acknowledgement", and for this, your best source is WordNet. You can check this [online on WordNet](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?o2=&o0=1&o8=1&o1=1&o7=&o5=&o9=&o6=&o3=&o4=&s=acknowledgement&i=3&h=10000#c).

There are quite a few WordNet-based libraries that you can use for this (e.g. in [JWNL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jwordnet/) in Java). In Python, NLTK should be able to get the derivationally related form you saw online:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn

acknowledgment_synset = wn.synset('acknowledgement.n.01')
acknowledgment_lemma = acknowledgment_synset.lemmas[1]

print(acknowledgment_lemma.derivationally_related_forms())
# [Lemma('admit.v.01.acknowledge'), Lemma('acknowledge.v.06.acknowledge')]
```