# import error for compat in NLTK and using BrowServer for browsing the NLTK Wordnet database for lemmatization

Tags: python-2.7, nltk, backwards-compatibility, trac, lemmatization

**Extension to the use case here** -
[NLTK words lemmatizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17684186/nltk-words-lemmatizing)

I have nltk installed on my computer(with all modules & corpus from the book). My use case is to explore and contrast some lemmatization and stemming approaches for my dataset (I tried Porter lemmatization, which worked)

I was trying to use the **lemmatization with Wordnet** as described by @Chthonic Project here [NLTK words lemmatizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17684186/nltk-words-lemmatizing) . However the source code it points to(see here http://nltk.org/_modules/nltk/app/wordnet_app.html) , needs compat module from nltk.

```
from nltk import compat
ImportError: cannot import name compat
```

I googled around for the import error of compat(and it looked like compatibilty?) and here's what I tried on my ubuntu box:-

**sudo  find . -name compat*** which returns the files below . I also tried **sudo find  -name "trac" -type d** which returns nothing .

I see that I should have found some modules with "trac/tests/functional/fixes" in a likewise folder /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.11.1-py2.4.egg/trac/tests/functional/

Source : http://biodegradablegeek.com/2008/08/workaround-for-importerror-cannot-import-name-compat-issue-in-trac-011x/#sthash.NhAThk6e.dpuf

*Questions :*

**1. What am I missing ?** And is this an issue with trac/tests?

**2. Is there a way to be able to use wordnet for lemmatization** (from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn works just fine. Post the import error is solved, how do I use this module http://nltk.org/_modules/nltk/app/wordnet_app.html (I was trying to build the source locally from this page, i.e. is the file browserver.py, when I hit the import error with compat)

*Tip :* If you are providing a solution, please also mention how to solve this on my windows environment (I use both windows & ubuntu interchangeably,depending on context)

**Files I see from find . -name compat***

```
ekta@ekta-VirtualBox:/usr/lib/python2.7$ sudo find . -name compat*
./dist-packages/numpy/numarray/compat.pyc
./dist-packages/numpy/numarray/compat.py
./dist-packages/numpy/distutils/compat.pyc
./dist-packages/numpy/distutils/compat.py
./dist-packages/numpy/compat
./dist-packages/numpy/oldnumeric/compat.pyc
./dist-packages/numpy/oldnumeric/compat.py
./dist-packages/twisted/python/compat.pyc
./dist-packages/twisted/python/compat.py
./dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/compat.pyc
./dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/compat.py
```

I am on python 2.7

Answer (score 3):

Lemmatizing using WordNet (Morphy, actually) in NLTK is simple:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn

wn.morphy('runs') # "run"
wn.morphy('leaves') # "leaf"
```

`wordnet_app` is a WordNet browser, not the NLTK WordNet API: you don't need it! Chthonic Project was talking about derivationally related forms, not lemmatizing, which are two different things.

By the way, the issue you had with `wordnet_app` and `compat` is that you copied a recent version of the file which was incompatible with your nltk distribution (compat is a recent NLTK module inspired from six that helps the transition to Python 3.). If you need `wordnet_app`, don't copy the source, simply use the version in your NLTK distribution!)

Comment: Follow up question 1) if I were to use derivationally related forms - will I get a single source like "Analysis", "Analyst", "Analyze" all have the same "stem" (or is that a different question all together? 2. How do I use the wordnet_app for python 2.7 - could you give a simple example ? 3. wn.morphy('analysis'), wn.morphy('analyst'),wn.morphy('analyze') - don't solve my problem here. I need the "stem"(and was assuming Lemmatization should give me that?)

Comment: re. Q1: I believe that derivationally related forms are more of a network than a tree - they don't all come down to one single source word but rather they're related words (even if they have a common lexical root that may not be a word by itself). re. Q3.: for clarification on stemming vs. lemmatizing (morphy() lemmatizes), take a look at http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/stemming-and-lemmatization-1.html, especially the paragraph starting with "However, the two words differ in their flavor. Stemming usually refers to...". Given that, please clarify your question! :)